# Control flow testing in white box - static or dynamic?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, control-flow

Yesterday I asked a question that happened to have another meaning inside. I can see that Control/data flow is often mentioned to be static analysis (when tools is used) or dynamic analysis testing in terms of white box testing. Could it be that automatic analysis tools can just help by creating graphs or they do actually test it with inputs (then it would not be static IMHO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have automatic analysis tools that perform symbolic execution. [Klee](http://klee.llvm.org) is an example of this. Basically it goes through the program trying to figure out what are the possible values of variables at different points. Using that it decides which input variables can cover which parts of the code. It even does some cool things with modelling file systems and environment variables. [Their paper](http://llvm.org/pubs/2008-12-OSDI-KLEE.pdf) is a fairly easy read and quite informative

So in general I think the distinction is not that simple. KLEE runs the code in a way, but I would not call that proper execution.